# Parameters Are Empty for Simple doGet Apps Script Function. Why?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, postman, query-string

Within Google Apps Scripts, I'm attempting to display the parameters being sent to my simple doGet function shown below:

```
function doGet(e) {
let response = e;
  return ContentService
.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response))
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

I attempt to throw in parameters to view them within Postman and no matter what I do, the output is empty.

```
[{
    "contentLength": -1,
    "parameter": {},
    "parameters": {},
    "queryString": "",
    "contextPath": ""
}][1]
```

My goal is this: How to get anything to show up in the parameters object?

Within Postman I am manually adding parameters and I replicated the same within my google browser. But it continues to be an empty object being returned.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you deployed a webapp?

Comment: Can you provide the detail of request from POSTMAN to your Web Apps?

Comment: @Cooper : Yes I have deployed a webapp. Anyone has access: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwj1osiia0r_oawCQIb_kMnn_0rVaVCLu4XS06-lR7-Hw34XpOEHnQzdZi99TkaMN7Z/exec .

Comment: @Tanaike : What detail specific are you looking for? I have the URL and used Postman itself to add the params. Here is an example of the URL I put into Postman: https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?lib=MPka8NWgs-ihLc44KDsLR2QIm5ToQ0m3X&user_content_key=ON5H54GNj6GP6i4GVsw7AR23cIZn9Qm_-bPZPvsDuj_5hU1csBNovwXSg9TmoVN302LMlYHpgfD9DVYwhF88RebvFkqWwcOJm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnO0NBzWaejsVpuk-nSwKFZT0XvxKPM3pG7nU1m4g1NYOwHSWSkLsvY8v6Qw6hJU4jV3pn3091cy3Xb0CpyLeK4qcM22rXJx2gg&Example=OfParams

Comment: Ruben's Answer led me to a solution. I was using the wrong URL as the link that google apps scripts provides you is the true URL you should use. It contains the '  /exec ' at the end. Longer explanation given as comment on the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter and parameters properties are empty objects because the URL used to do the HTTP GET call doesn't include a query string

Instead of using

`https://... /exec`

use something like

`https://... /exec?givenName=John&surname=Doe`

The parameter property is `{givenName:'John',surname:'Doe'}`.

The parameters property is `{givenName:['John'],surname:['Doe']}`.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Ruben. Looking at the documentation finally helped me have that important click moment. Here is a rundown of my issue: When I click on the deployment link for my site it looks like this: 

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwj1osiia0r_oawCQIb_kMnn_0rVaVCLu4XS06-lR7-Hw34XpOEHnQzdZi99TkaMN7Z/exec . 

When the page finally loads, the url would change dramatically to a very long string that would lack the final ' /exec ' portion. I was putting that changed URL in Postman which caused my issues. Thank you Ruben and others for the quick responses!

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JacobHawkins. That have not happened to me when deploying a web-app in Google Apps Script. Anyway,  I'm glad that your issue was solved.